# How to open a file using a menu bar in a user control and setting the text in a richtextbox in the main window, WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controls

I'm trying to open a document that has a filter of `txt` or `rtf`. This document should open in a `richtextbox` in the `mainwindow` and I have a `usercontrol` with a `menu item` called open, so that when I open it, it should open up a `openfiledialog` window and it has. The thing is I can't open the document as the event is in the `usercontrol` and I can't called the `richtextbox` from the `usercontrol`. Can someone help me called the `richtextbox` from the `usercontrol`?

Comment: Please edit question (click on "edit" at bottom of question) and add a small snippet of code of what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

in mainWindows.cs have this codes

```
string str="";
        public string textContent
        {
            set { if (value != null) richtextbox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, value); else richtextbox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, ""); }
            get { richtextbox .Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out str); return str; }

        }
```

and for called the richtextbox from the usercontrol

just call mainWindows.textContent to read or write text to it

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :D

Comment: your welcome if its helped you plz add reputation for me tnx